# Opening Multiple Links In ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that takes some user input from a view, the reports the user wants, and creates a parameter string from it in the controller, and I need to open up multiple report urls after the query string is created but not sure how:

**View snippet:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.report1)  Report1
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.report2) Report2
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.report3) Report3

<input type="submit" value="Index" />
```

**controller snippet**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model) {

string parameters="&id="+model";

if(model.report1==true) 
{
    string report1="http://<urlhere>"+parameters;
}
//CONTINUE for the other two reports as well
}
```

I need to open the reports in multiple tabs.  I have researched it extensively and it seems like you can't open multiple tabs from the controller, so I'm at a loss.  I considered putting the urls in a list, passing them into a View, and using JavaScript to open them on the page load, but I honestly am not sure how to do that in Javascript and MVC.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this using PartialView.

Comment: Just show links to multiple results. Opening links on page view will probably make the popup blocker act up. Asking the user to click on links is less dubious w/r/t usability than asking them to disable a popup blocker somewhere in parts of browser settings dialog they've never seen before.

Comment: Per HTTP protocol design, you can only send one file per request. Popping up files via JavaScript is not a good idea either. You should consider sending them in a single zip file.

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out this is not possible from the server side, so pass the report URLs to the client and use something like the following JavaScript:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ReportUri))
{
    <a id="reportLink" href="@Model.ReportUri" target="_blank">REPORT</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var link = document.getElementById('reportLink');
        link.click();
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    </script>
}
```

Please keep in mind, that popup-blockers will most likely block this, so you should tell this somehow to the user. Also maybe it is usefull to keep the links on the page in your case (so remove the last line of my script) to give the user the chance to manually open them when they get blocked...